Why ServiceLoader.load(...) runs ok, but fails my tests?
I have a Spring Boot project with 2 jigsaw modules (java 21).
Inner module with only one public package with interfaces and DTOs; also it provides an implementation for UseCase service:
module com.sample.domain {
    exports com.sample.domain.api;

    provides com.sample.domain.api.UseCase
            with com.sample.domain.internal.UseCaseImpl;
}

Outer module that requires the first one and uses the providing service:
open module com.sample.web {
    requires com.sample.domain;

    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.web;

    requires org.apache.tomcat.embed.core;

    exports com.sample.main;

    uses com.sample.api.UseCase;
}

I create a Spring bean for UseCase using ServiceLoader:
@Bean
UseCase useCase() {
    return ServiceLoader.load(UseCase.class).findFirst().orElseThrow();
}

When I run my Spring Boot application from my IDE it executes ok and UseCase bean is instantiated and injected.
But when I run mvn test, ServiceLoader.load(UseCase.class).findFirst() is empty.
I have the feeling like mvn test is ignoring the module-info.java statement: uses com.sample.api.UseCase;

It’s not the duty of Maven to handle a uses clause in a module-info at all. All it cares for, is the pom.xml (which you didn’t include). If we assume that the built jar files include the module-info.class (as it works within the IDE), check whether these jar files are correctly placed on the module path rather than class path in the mvn test environment.

Reference from the original source could be of help.

@Naman following your link to maven site, I end in this multi-module maven project with 2 module-info.java (one in main and another in test). Can we have more than one module-info.java in same project? I thought we can have only one. If I try that in my project my IDE complains "the module-info is already defined in the project", https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/tree/master/surefire-its/src/test/resources/maven-multimodule-project-with-jpms/com.foo.impl
